# Using Rails 3 gem Manifesto

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use the HTML5 manifest function using a gem called Manifesto. I am stuck on the instructions for usage. I cannot figure out where those settings are supposed to go.

Any ideas? Perhaps a better gem?

https://github.com/johntopley/manifesto#readme

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you settings in a file under `config/initializers/`. Use an informational name (like `manifesto.rb`). However you don't need a config with the basic usage.

In your `Gemfile` file, add:

```
gem 'manifesto'
```

then install via bundle:

```
bundle install
```

create the file `app/controllers/manifest_controller.rb`

```
class ManifestController < ApplicationController
  def show
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/cache-manifest'
    render :text => Manifesto.cache, :layout => false
  end
end
```

in `config/routes.rb` add:

```
match '/manifest' => 'manifest#show'
```

Restart your app and view the result at http://localhost:3000/manifest

You can pass the option directly to `Manifesto.cache` like:

```
# change
render :text => Manifesto.cache, :layout => false
# to
render :text => Manifesto.cache(:directory => './mobile', :compute_hash => false), :layout => false
```

Or use a YAML file and an initializer.

The `config/manifesto.yaml` file:

```
# directory is relative to Rails root
directory: './mobile'
compute_hash: false
```

The `config/initializers/manifesto.rb` file:

```
# Load the config file and convert keys from strings in symbols (the manifesto gem need symbolized options).
MANIFESTO_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'manifesto.yml').to_s).inject({}){|config,(k,v)| config[k.to_sym] = v; config}
```

And pass the loaded config to `Manifesto.cache` like:

```
# change
render :text => Manifesto.cache, :layout => false
# to
render :text => Manifesto.cache(MANIFESTO_CONFIG), :layout => false
```

Comment: Looking good, thanks! What exactly do I put in the manifesto.rb file?

Comment: @Jonathan Clark - You don't need a config file (so you don't need the manifesto.rb file).

Comment: But where do I select which folder to be used?